# Large encrypted files to be sent in REST API response

Tags: rest, json

JWE is often used in REST APIs to send encrypted messages. However, I need to send a file that could be GBs in size. I have tried to find any information about the maximum length limit of the plaintext that can/should be the input for a JWE serialization. I could not find anything in the JWE spec at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516.

Even though the standard may not define a limit, JWE would not be an ideal way to send files that are several GBs in size. It would be impractical to hold the entire file contents in memory and create even a JWE Compact Serialization form of the encrypted content. Files this big would typically be read in chunks and, in Java, a [`CipherOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) could be used to generate the ciphertext. Is there a way to send this ciphertext in a JWE envelop? Is chunking the response possible? If not, what would be the recommended method to transfer large files in an encrypted format as the response to a REST API request?

Comment: Maybe look at it sideways: let files be handled normally by the webserver, just encrypt them (either once or on access depending on your needs) by any symmetric cipher, and then use JWE to only communicate the key used by this encryption to users needing it to decrypt the files. On call to your API, your application could locally encrypt the file, make it accessible through some non-deterministic URL and reply to client through JWE with this URL and the key needed to decrypt the file. The client would then separately fetch the file, and that would be handled nicely size-wise by the webserver

Comment: Have you found anything you can share?